# How can i do that on mouse enter event the new form/usercontrol will move to the center of Form1?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void zedGraphControl1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            zedGraphControl1.Location = new Point(this.Width / 2, this.Height / 2);
        }
```

But this will make the left side of the control in the middle of form1 and then all the right side will get out of form1 area.

How can i make that the whole control will be in the middle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've correctly found the center of your main Winform and placed your graph control there. To center it on that point, simply remove half of its width and height.

```
private void zedGraphControl1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    zedGraphControl1.Location = new Point(Width / 2 - zedGraphControl1.Width/2, Height / 2 - zedGraphControl1.Height/2);
}
```

And sorry, but I love MS Paint :

[image]